# mysql query returns 500 Internal Server Error for larger join rows

Tags: mysql

- I have checked suggested similar questions and related questions, but I couldn’t find a question similar to this issue. I am working on CentOS6 VPS, Apache server.

If I run the following mysql query in my PHP application or directly phpmyadmin (through browser) it is returning **500 Internal Server Error** . But If I run the same query in mysql (through terminal) it returns 44864 rows in 2.62 seconds.
And also it returns correct result to some other "town_id" (which have small amount of products assigned to that given town_id).

There is no log in apache2/access_log & error_log, mysql error log neither mysql-slow-queries regarding this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t.pid) FROM 
( SELECT Product.id AS pid FROM products Product 
LEFT JOIN productagents Productagent ON Productagent.product_id = Product.id 
LEFT JOIN productlocations Productlocation ON Productlocation.product_id = Product.id 
WHERE 1 AND Product.active = 1 AND Productagent.saleorent = 1 
AND ( Productlocation.town_id = 1682 ) 
AND (Productagent.product_status_id = 1) AND Productagent.product_status_id != 17 
ORDER BY Product.updated_at desc ) 
AS t
```

I just query the productlocation table, like below. And it returns 172388 rows.

```
SELECT id FROM `productlocations` WHERE town_id = 1682
```

Followings are my indexes in each table:

> Table: products, Index name: PRIMARY columns: id
>
> Table: products, Index name: idx_act_updt columns: id, active, updated_at
>
> Table: productagents, Index name: PRIMARY columns: id
>
> Table: productagents, Index name: idx_prod_sor_sts columns: product_id, saleorent, product_status_id
>
> Table: productlocations, Index name: PRIMARY columns: id
>
> Table: productlocations, Index name: idx_prod_town columns: product_id, town_id

Comment: Apache may be logging that to a different location than you looked. A 500 error in PHP always means you should turn error reporting all the way up and if possible display errors on screen (while testing only). In the PHP: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  You may be exceeding PHP's memory limit or max execution time.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : Yes you correct. I increased the memory up to 8000M (8GB). Then only it's worked. Could you please suggest me to do something else rather increasing memory limit? This is easyapache4 configured server, so I have checked every possible places for logs. There are mysql-slow-queries.log file but nothing related to this.

Comment: Increasing PHP's memory limit _is_ the correct solution if your query is expected to return such a large rowset that you exceed its default.  If you post the PHP code, it is possible there may be efficiency to gain somewhere in the code, but increasing the memory limit is a typical strategy.  You probably do not need it at 8G however. The default is `128M` and it may work for you by just increasing it to `256M`.